# return t == null ? -1 : t.height; what do ? and : mean?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have encountered this piece of code to compute height of an AVL tree node:

```
private int height (AvlNode<T> t) {
  return t == null ? -1 : t.height; 
}
```

What do the `?` and `:` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
if (t==null)
    return -1;
else
    return t.height;
```

The conditional operator  **?  :** 
Is used to return the result of either expressions depending on the value of the 1st expression.

It works by evaluating **boolean expr** and then deciding which expression to evaluate.

Answer (score 7):

This is a ternary operator. The general syntax is:

```
cond ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

where `cond` is an expression returning a boolean value. The entire expression at large is evaluated to `ifTrue` when `cond` is true, otherwise it is evaluated to `ifFalse`. Of course, both `ifTrue` and `ifFalse` must be of compatible types (note that `null` is possible for objects).

The code above is, in practice, exactly equivalent to the following:

```
if (t == null)
    return -1;
return t.height;
```

This is a very classical operator found in many languages. One language which does NOT have this operator is Python.

Comment: python have something similar `ifTrue if cond else ifFalse`

Comment: @furas yes, but not this operator per se

Answer (score 1):

it is like a if test.

your example is similar to this code:

```
if (t == null) return -1;
else return t.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

if t is null it will return -1, else it will return t.hight. This is a cleaner way to implement null check instead of having

```
if(t==null)
   return -1
else
   return t.hight
```

but it might look more cryptic then the "if approach"

Answer (score 0):

```
(a > b) ? a : b;
```

> is an expression which returns one of two values, a
>
> > or b. The condition, (a > b), is tested. If it is true the first
> >     value, a, is returned. If it is false, the second value, b, is
> >     returned. Whichever value is returned is dependent on the conditional
> >     test, a > b. The condition can be any expression which returns a
> >     boolean value.